# What is the name of this purple leaved hanging plant?

Tags: identification, indoors

One of my hanging plant's name I don't know, can you identify it? here are its pictures:

Full Plant:
[image]

Leaves Front Side:
[image]

Leaves Back Side: (Purple side)
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*Tradescantia zebrina*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradescantia_zebrina) (previously known as *Zebrina pendula*), although it is often confused with other Tradescantia varieties such as T. fluminensis.

Answer (score 5):

The plant you ask about with purple and green leaves is called "Wandering Jew" in my neck of the woods.

Comment: Yes Right, that is it's local name! Officially it is 'Tradescantia zebrina' as Bamboo's answered!